# display only the wp_nav_menu, which has the current-menu-item

Tags: menus, filters

i have a problem displaying only the menu with wp_nav_menu, in which the *current-menu-item* is in.

Heres what i got:

```
function register_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'sidebar-menu' => __('Sidebar Menu'),
      'first-menu' => __('Menu 1'),
      'second-menu' => __('Menu 2'),
      'third-menu' => __('Menu 3')
    )
  );
}
add_action('init', 'register_menus')
```

and on the page.php i'm doing

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'first-menu')); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'second-menu')); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'third-menu')); ?>
```

when i now open up a page, which is in Menu 2, i can style it with *.current-menu-item* - so no problem here.

but i want to display only the one menu, which has the *.current-menu-item* in it (Menu 2). the other ones (Menu 1, Menu 3) should be *display: none;*

is there a way to accomplish that?
i thought of a walker, a filter or a simple if-statement, which checks for the menu, which has the *.current-menu-item* but i can't handle it myself :-(

thank you very much

Comment: ok, i think theres no css-way until css4. so i used a JS, simulating this css4 behavior

https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75607/check-if-page-is-in-a-certain-menu

Answer (score 1):

Just intercept the nav classes and search for the `current-menu-item` class. This will give you the `$item` it's associated with.

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'get_active_class', 10, 2 );
function get_active_class( $classes, $item )
{
    if ( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes) ) {
        // We found the active class!: $item
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Now just grab your nav menu and apply the needed css classes or `style="display:none"` to the others.